# How do I share exchange/outlook calendar to ics format somewhere Google calendar can access

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar, webdav

I use Exchange/Outlook at work and Google Calendar for everything else. I want to get my Outlook calendar into Google Calendar using "Other Calendars -> Add by URL", so I can see free/busy information.

I need some kind of hosting/service - or something that will let outlook publish using WEBDAV - and lets Google Calendar access the same file without authentication (Google Calendar does not support that).

How can that be done?

[image]

[image]

I am aware of the potential privacy implications of sharing the calendar publicly, but since I will only be publishing free/busy info, I am not concerned.

Answer (score 2):

iCalX does that - and it is free.

http://icalx.com/

Took me 2 minutes to set up and account and get it working.